# MediaWIki Session idle time

Tags: session, cookies, mediawiki, session-cookies

in one mediaWiki project it happens to me that after a user has been idle for some period (like 20 minutes) he gets automatically logged out.

I have already tried to set in LocalSettings.php 
$wgCookieExpiration = 60*60*24*365; and 
$wgCookieExpiration = 0; but it does not seem to work, I still get logged out.

I have tested this in Chrome and Firefox.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Same problem here. General PHP sessions are not terminated but MediaWiki sessions are. It turned out to be related to $wgObjectCacheSessionExpiry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to eliminate possible causes:

1. Did you login on the same pc with another account? Does it also time out after 20 min?
2. Have you tried using the account on a different pc, do you see the same problem?

I've had issues with mediawiki sessions before,that disappeared after an Apache reboot. Did you try rebooting Apache?